# Jenkins One maven project dependent on another Running Issue

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am trying to schedule job on jenkins which is dependent on another Maven project, I tried everything pipeline, multiphase phase project, but I am getting below issue repetitively;

**Issue**

Could not resolve dependencies for project com.ctl.it.qa:Project-1:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.ctl.it.qa:Projects-2:jar:1.1.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

The above error is not expected because I have already have maven project called "Projects-2". It should pickup dependency from here.

Nee to know what I am missing.

Will Appreciate for complete Solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the query, Jenkins should trigger in the below order
**Project 1** -> Should be triggered first -> Creates Jar
(After Successful generation of jar)
**Project 2** -> Trigger project2

Before automating it , try manually triggering the projects. 
If you still get the current error, try Force update, so add **-U** along with the current goals.

```
mvn clean install -U
```

And for effectively trigger a build based on a dependent build, you could try the 
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

Comment: I tried with mvn install, I can see the jars is created in target repository of first project, but my second project is not able to take that jar, it stills searches in central repository which is not expected.

Comment: did u try offline mode?